# VBA: Use Class module / Collection and/or dynamic array?

Tags: vba, excel

My problem:

I have multiple product structures that I need to be able to read through. I do not know ahead of time how many levels deep the product structure goes.  For Example I could have the following:

Product A uses the following components

- A1
- A2
- A3
- A4

but component A3 may be a sub assembly which has its own product structure that would need to be pulled.  So I would then end up with the complete product structure for Product A looking like the following:

A uses:

- A1
- A2
- A3 (uses the following components):

  - A3A
  - A3B (uses the following components):
    *A3B1
    *A3B2
    *A3B3
  - A3C
  - A3D
- A4

and so on.

My current code uses an array to contain the information retrieved via a DB query as shown here

```
Dim NumRecords As Integer
Dim X As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim PPS() As String 'Product structure returned from database query for the parent item
Dim ParentName as String ' Parent Product
Dim Plt as String ' Plant of Manufacture
Dim DBPath as string 'File path for the database


Set db = OpenDatabase(DBPath)
sSQL = "SELECT Component, NumberUsed FROM ProdStructMstr WHERE (((Parent)='" & ParentName & "') AND ((Plant)='" & Plt & "')) ORDER BY Component;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
If Not rs.EOF Then NumRecords = rs.RecordCount
If NumRecords > 0 Then
    ReDim PPS(NumRecords - 1, 1)
    rs.MoveFirst
    For X = 0 To NumRecords - 1
        PPS(X, 0) = rs!Component
        PPS(X, 1) = rs!NumberUsed
        rs.MoveNext
    Next X
Else
    MsgBox "ERROR: DB Table Empty or Not Found!", vbExclamation, "DATA ERROR"
End If
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

The problem I have with this is that it isn't capable of going further than 1 layer deep on the product structure, which means it won't pull the information for sub-assemblies.  I think I want to use a class module and a collection to over come this but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

The information for the product structure of the sub assembly A3 is listed in the ProdStructMstr table with A3 listed as the Parent and the components listed.

An example of how the DB table looks for this would be:

```
Plant    |    Parent    |    Component    |    NumberUsed
Z        |    A         |    A1           |    1
Z        |    A         |    A2           |    3
Z        |    A         |    A3           |    1
Z        |    A         |    A4           |    2
Z        |    A3        |    A3A          |    1
Z        |    A3        |    A3B          |    1
Z        |    A3        |    A3C          |    2
Z        |    A3        |    A3D          |    1
Z        |    A3B       |    A3B1         |    1
Z        |    A3B       |    A3B2         |    4
Z        |    A3B       |    A3B3         |    1
```

Comment: Can you post what the array looks like?  I don't quite understand what you mean by "it isn't capable of going further than 1 layer deep on the product structure".

Comment: The `SQL` query `WHERE (((Parent)='" & ParentName & "')` returns result for _only one_ parent.In the example of how the DB table looks it would for e.g. `Parent = 'A'` be the first four rows. What when you remove the `WHERE` and get all the data for the plant?

Comment: @ Dee - The plant is used as a filter to trim down the number of records returned.  The user will enter in a parent item and a qty that they want to make.  I need to be able to recursively follow the product structure all the way down to the raw material so that I know that in order to produce 10 pieces of product A I need 10 of A1, 30 of A2, 10 of A3A, 10 of A3B1, 40 of A3B2, 10 of A3B3, 20 of A4

Comment: @J.Garth -The array is the dynamic array that I'm populating in the code above (  PPS()  )    My mind says that I want to create a class module, call it "PS", and stuff the PPS() array in it and then for each sub assembly found in the product structure, create a new instance of "PS" and store that portion of the product structure.  The problem with this is that I'd need to be able to dynamically create variable names for each instance of the "PS" class as I have no way of knowing ahead of time how many I'll need.  The obvious problem with this is that I can't dynamically create variable names

Comment: Can you post an example of the data in the array for better visualisation of the problem?

Comment: its not an elegant way to do it but I finally got something that appears to be working.  In short, what I did was create a UDT called `Part` with an `.IsSub` property and then defined my `PPS()` array as `Part` type.  Then while processing each of the components, I checked the component against the table to check if it is a sub assembly and if so, set `IsSub` property to `True`, then created a function that pulls the product structure for the sub assembly and if any of the sub assembly's components are sub assemblies themselves, call the function again to handle that part of the prod structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long answer, but maybe it will help

I'm providing 2 versions to illustrate the use of nested dictionaries for your case

Test data (main section is light-orange):

[image]

---

> **Version 1**

Output:

> ```
> ------ ShowAllData
> Item: A, SubItem: A1, Value: 1
> Item: A, SubItem: A2, Value: 3
> Item: A, SubItem: A3, Value: 1
> Item: A, SubItem: A4, Value: 2
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3A, Value: 1
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3B, Value: 1
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3C, Value: 2
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3D, Value: 1
> Item: A3B, SubItem: A3B1, Value: 1
> Item: A3B, SubItem: A3B2, Value: 4
> Item: A3B, SubItem: A3B3, Value: 1
> ------ ShowData (A3)
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3A, Value: 1
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3B, Value: 1
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3C, Value: 2
> Item: A3, SubItem: A3D, Value: 1
> ------ ShowData (A3B2)
> Item: A3B, SubItem: A3B2, Value: 4
> ```

---

Version 1 has two main procedures

- one that reads all rows from Sheet1: `ReadData()`
- the second generates nested dictionaries (recursively) by rows: `SetItms()`

  - col B (Parent) - lvl 1 - These items are Keys in the top-level dictionary
  - col C (Component) - lvl 2 - Values of top-level dictionary, and Keys for sub-dictionaries
  - col D (NumberUsed) - lvl 3 - Values in each sub-dictionary

---

> This uses dictionaries and **late binding is slow**: <strike>CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")</strike>
>
> **Early binding is fast**: VBA Editor -> **Tools** -> **References** -> Add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

---

```
Option Explicit

'In VBA Editor add a reference: Tools -> References -> Add Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Private Const SEP = "------ "

Public Sub ReadData()
    Const TLC = 2   'TLC = Top-level column (B: Parent)
    Dim ur As Variant, r As Long, ubR As Long, parents As Dictionary
    Dim lvl1 As String, lvl2 As String, lvl3 As String

    ur = Sheet1.UsedRange
    ubR = UBound(ur, 1)
    Set parents = New Dictionary
    parents.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'or: vbBinaryCompare

    For r = 2 To ubR
        lvl1 = Trim(CStr(ur(r, TLC)))
        lvl2 = Trim(CStr(ur(r, TLC + 1)))
        lvl3 = Trim(CStr(ur(r, TLC + 2)))
        SetItms Array(lvl1, lvl2, lvl3), parents
    Next
    ShowAllData parents
    ShowData parents, "A3"
    ShowData parents, "A3B2"
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub SetItms(ByRef itms As Variant, ByRef parents As Dictionary)
    Dim ub As Long, subItms() As String, i As Long, children As Dictionary

    ub = UBound(itms)
    If ub > 1 Then
        ReDim subItms(ub - 1)
        For i = 1 To ub
            subItms(i - 1) = itms(i)
        Next
        If Not parents.Exists(itms(0)) Then
            Set children = New Dictionary
            children.CompareMode = vbTextCompare   'or: vbBinaryCompare
            SetItms subItms, children              '<-- recursive call
            parents.Add itms(0), children
        Else
            Set children = parents(itms(0))
            SetItms subItms, children              '<-- recursive call
        End If
    Else
        If Not parents.Exists(itms(0)) Then parents.Add itms(0), itms(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

The next 2 subs are only used to output data from dictionaries: `ShowAllData()` and `ShowData()`

---

```
Private Sub ShowAllData(ByRef itms As Dictionary)
    Dim l1 As Variant, l2 As Variant
    Debug.Print SEP & "ShowAllData"
    For Each l1 In itms
        For Each l2 In itms(l1)
            Debug.Print "Item: " & l1 & ", SubItem: " & l2 & ", Value: " & itms(l1)(l2)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ShowData(ByRef itms As Dictionary, ByVal itmName As String)
    Dim l1 As Variant, l2 As Variant, isParent As Boolean, done As Boolean
    Debug.Print SEP & "ShowData (" & itmName & ")"
    For Each l1 In itms
        isParent = l1 = itmName
        If isParent Then
            For Each l2 In itms(l1)
                Debug.Print "Item: " & l1 & ", SubItem: " & l2 & ", Value: " & itms(l1)(l2)
            Next
        End If
        If isParent Then Exit For
    Next
    If Not isParent Then
        For Each l1 In itms
            For Each l2 In itms(l1)
              done = l2 = itmName
              If done Then
                Debug.Print "Item: " & l1 & ", SubItem: " & l2 & ", Value: " & itms(l1)(l2)
                Exit For
              End If
            Next
            If done Then Exit For
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

> **Version 2**

Output:

> ```
> Row 1, Col 1:   --->   Plant
> Row 1, Col 2:   --->   Parent
> Row 1, Col 3:   --->   Component
> Row 1, Col 4:   --->   NumberUsed
> Row 1, Col 5:   --->   Test Col 1
> Row 1, Col 6:   --->   Test Col 2
> Row 1, Col 7:   --->   Test Col 3
> Row 2, Col 1:   --->   Z
> Row 2, Col 2:   --->   A
> Row 2, Col 3:   --->   A1
> Row 2, Col 4:   --->   1
> Row 2, Col 5:   --->   E1
> Row 2, Col 6:   --->   F1
> Row 2, Col 7:   --->   G1
> ...
> Row 12, Col 1:   --->   Z
> Row 12, Col 2:   --->   A3B
> Row 12, Col 3:   --->   A3B3
> Row 12, Col 4:   --->   1
> Row 12, Col 5:   --->   E11
> Row 12, Col 6:   --->   F11
> Row 12, Col 7:   --->   G11
> ```

---

Version 2 simply creates a 2-level nesting of dictionaries (level 1 = rows, level 2 = columns)

---

```
Public Sub NestedList()
    Dim ur As Variant, itms As Dictionary, subItms As Dictionary
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long

    ur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Set itms = New Dictionary
    itms.CompareMode = vbTextCompare   'or: vbBinaryCompare

    lr = UBound(ur, 1)
    lc = UBound(ur, 2)

    For r = 1 To lr
        Set subItms = New Dictionary
        itms.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For c = 1 To lc
            subItms.Add Key:=c, Item:=Trim(CStr(ur(r, c)))
        Next
        itms.Add Key:=r, Item:=subItms
        Set subItms = Nothing
    Next
    NestedListShow itms
End Sub

Private Sub NestedListShow(ByRef itms As Dictionary)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To itms.Count
        For c = 1 To itms(r).Count
            Debug.Print "Row " & r & ", Col " & c & ":   --->   " & itms(r)(c)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Notes:

- you could place all procedures (both versions) in the same module
- this assumes that UsedRange on Sheet1 starts at cell A1, and is contiguous

Comment: I may be able to use a dictionary (never used any before) I'll have to give it some thought as my data is returned from the database on a mainframe via the SQL passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you are tying to query your mainframe database as if it were a relational database.  But based on the example table you provided, it's not.  That table is not normalized.

So I'm guessing that in your sql query,

`"SELECT Component, NumberUsed FROM ProdStructMstr WHERE (((Parent)='" & ParentName & "') AND ((Plant)='" & Plt & "')) ORDER BY Component;"`

`Parent` probably equals "A" and so the recordset you are getting back only consists of components A1, A2, A3, & A4.

If that is the case, then you need to change the SQL query to use the `Like` keyword as below (you may have to adjust the syntax)

`"SELECT Component, NumberUsed FROM ProdStructMstr WHERE (((Parent)=Like '" & ParentName & " *') AND ((Plant)='" & Plt & "')) ORDER BY Component;"`

This will return all records where the Parent **starts with** "A", instead of just the records where the Parent equals A.  You will end up with a lot of duplicates you will need to filter out but you should at least have all of the data that you need.

Comment: This would work but except for the products which use common components, in which case those components will be missed.  


After spending a long weekend with it in the back of my mind, I think what will work is a place holder array (ie Prod(?,3) that I can dump each of the components into and have flags to indicate if it has been checked for being a sub-assembly and if it is, flag it so that i can pull its structure and then flag it as done.

Comment: I don't understand why common components among products would be a problem because your sql statement indicates that you are calling out the products one at a time.  I probably just don't fully understand your goal or the problem but based on what you've shared, the root of the problem seems to be the way the database you're querying is set up.  My feeling is that you don't have any control over the database and you're just looking for a work around so hopefully the solution you came up with solves the problem.

Comment: The common components may be sub assemblies themselves.  So product B could be made of components B1, B2, A3.  In this case, a 'like' statement in the SQL will completely ignore the A3 shared component.

Comment: I think you'd need to post an example of the table for that example because according the to table you posted earlier there are only two columns in the table that deal with products and components:  Parent and Component.  So if you're querying by Parent and not getting all of the components then it seems like the problem is with the table.